# Interpretation of "and"

Tags: and-or

Consider the sentence,

> A is better than B and C.

Does it mean A is better than B and C individually?
Or, A is better than B and C combined?

Consider the following paragraph picked from [this blog post](http://amauryablogs.blogspot.in/2016/07/dangers-of-network-based-on-invisible.html).

> "Also note that nepotism is not limited to college admissions only. Every other domain, which is supposed to be merit driven like public job recruitments/promotions, tender allocations etc., is susceptible to such corruptions. **In all such domains, invisible networks will be far more successful in hiding corrupt behaviours than visible networks and individuals."**

I am referring to the usage of *and* in last line - *"...than visible networks and individuals"*.

Comment: Either, depending on context.  Please add some more context information to your question.

Comment: @Max: The problem is when questioners fail to supply sufficient *context*, we're all in danger of only addressing the first context that comes to mind. The best approach is therefore to request more context in comments (or to closevote for *lack* of context), but of course even competent speakers may fail to recognize immediately that some usage may have different meanings in different contexts, so it's always going to be an issue if we don't have a link to some *specific* source citing the usage in question.

Comment: @Max: I don't think it really depends on context. I think the only time it can mean B and C combined is when "B and C" is already a precombined unit (like, "cereal is a healthier breakfast than steak and eggs", or "they split into pairs, except they had an odd number, so Melanie had to do it alone. Even so, she got a higher score than Billy and Alyssa."). When that's not the case, I think you need to explicitly say "combined" or "put together" (or similar) in order to enable that interpretation.

Comment: @ruakh when you say "the only time" isn't that the same as saying "there are a small number of contexts in which"...?

Comment: @MaxWilliams: Sort of? I meant my comment more like, "She never wears perfume. The only time she wears cosmetics is . . ."; but if you feel that all cosmetics count as perfume, then sure. :-P

Comment: @ruakh that analogy has completely confused me, I have no idea what point you're trying to make.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: What I'm saying is, there's no context where "A is better than B and C" can mean "A is better than B and C combined". If Alice got 95%, and Bob and Carol each got 90%, there's no risk that "Alice did better than Bob and Carol" will be misinterpreted as a mistaken claim that 95% > 90% + 90%. However, if "B and C" is already a single semantic unit, then "A is better than B and C" doesn't forcibly split that unit apart to produce the meaning "A and is better than either B or C".

Comment: @MaxWilliams: (For example, "cereal is a healthier breakfast than steak and eggs" does not mean "cereal is a healthier breakfast than steak and eggs combined"; rather, it means "cereal is a healthier breakfast than one consisting of steak and eggs". They're similar, but obviously not the same.)

Comment: @MaxWilliams context is added.